# MSVC compiler error when overloading template with enum parameter

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++, enums

I try to write templates that take enum classes as non-type template parameters like in the code below.

When I try to compile this code with MSVC2017, I get the following compiler errors:

```
source_file.cpp(16): error C2668: 'g': ambiguous call to overloaded function
source_file.cpp(10): note: could be 'void g<E2::v>(void)'
source_file.cpp(6): note: or       'void g<E1::v>(void)'
source_file.cpp(16): note: while trying to match the argument list '()'
```

Clang and gcc, on the other hand, compile my code without any error messages and output

```
g1
g2
```

as expected.

```
#include <iostream>

enum class E1{v};
enum class E2{v};

template<E1 e1> void g(){
    std::cout << "g1" << std::endl;
}

template<E2 e2> void g(){
    std::cout << "g2" << std::endl;
}

int main(){
    g<E1::v>();
    g<E2::v>();
}
```

(This code can be tested on [rextester](https://rextester.com/KTQXB32499).)

Is there a mistake in my code or is it rather an issue with MSVC? Do you know any ways to work around this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a mistake in my code or is it rather an issue with MSVC?

To me, it looks like an error in MSVC.

> Do you know any ways to work around this problem?

It seems that if `E1::v` and `E2::v` have different values, then it compiles correctly.  I tested this by changing your second enum to this:

```
enum class E2 { v = 2 };
```